# Convergence of conditional expectation of a function

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, let $p(\cdot|y)$ be the probability density function of $X|Y=y$ and let $h(X,Y)$ be a function of $X$ and $Y$.

> **Question:** Suppose that $p(x|y)$ is differentiable in $y$, that $h(\cdot,\cdot)$ is continuous and $|h(x,y)|\le B$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Do we have the following? If $y_n\to y$ then
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)\mid Y = y_n) = \mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)\mid Y = y)
> \end{align*}

**My thoughts:** I would like to write

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)|Y = y_n) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int h(x,y_n)p(x|y_n) dx \\
&= \int \lim_{n\to\infty} h(x,y_n)p(x|y_n) dx \\
&= \int h(x,y)p(x|y) dx \\
&= \mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)|Y = y).
\end{align*}
However to move the limit in the integral I wanted to use the dominated convergence theorem, which doesn't clearly apply because $p(\cdot|y_n)$ might not be necessarily bounded over $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by an integrable function.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the answer to my own question, would love it if someone could confirm. The proof is as follows:
\begin{align}
|\mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)&|Y = y_n) - \mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)|Y = y)| \\
&\le \int |h(x,y_n)p(x|y_n) - h(x,y)p(x|y)|dx \\
&\le \int  |h(x,y_n)|\times|p(x|y_n) - p(x|y)| dx \\
&+ \int |h(x,y_n) - h(x,y)|\times p(x|y) dx 
\end{align}
All functions within the integrals are continuous in $y$. The first integral is bounded by 
$$
\int  |h(x,y_n)|\times|p(x|y_n) - p(x|y)| dx \le B\int  |p(x|y_n) - p(x|y)| dx,
$$
which converges to zero by Scheffe's lemma applied to $p(x|y_n)\to p(x|y)$. The function inside the second integral is bounded by $B\times p(x\mid y)$, so that the integral converges to zero by the dominated convergence theorem.